# Recyclerview: update view elements outside the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view that looks like this:

[image]

At the start, these circle icons are empty. I need to update every icon of my recycler to be from empty to full within an interval of 5 seconds (see the image above).

I actually can update these icons, but my problem is:
If I have 20 items, I'll need to scroll the recycler in order to see every item. Whenever I scroll the recycler, the last 4-5 items don't get updated from empty to full.

I just need to update the UI, I don't need to remove or add anything to the recyclerview. I've already tried to use notifyDataSetChanged(), notifyItemChanged(), but nothing worked so far.
What's your suggestion? Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like a recycling problem.
Share the code of the view model and the adapter.

Comment: The recycler view can use an itemview for multiple items in your data set to represent items. This comes from its recycling nature. If you want to see the most recent item views in the screen you must keep the state information in your data set, by the time the recycler view decides to recycle an item view with another item in your data list the recent state of that item shoul be done before it calls its `onBindViewHolder` method. So you must apply the state changes of item you made while binding. Otherwise the changes may not be seen for the out of screen items.

Comment: Yeah - when the RecyclerView displays an item in one of its reusable ViewHolders, it needs to know whether to set the circle as full or not. So you need to store that data somewhere, and update it as the user interacts with things. And you probably need to persist it too, e.g. if the user rotates the screen, you don't want to lose that visual state right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one strategy. Have one function in your adapter to start/reset the animation. You can call it when you set the data list. In `onBindViewHolder` you calculate when relative to now the icon should change to filled (could be in the past). The ViewHolder class either immediately shows the filled icon if the time is negative, or else it posts a delayed runnable to change it in the future. You'll need to cancel any previous delayed runnable so when views get recycled, they always get updated to the correct state.

```
//Inside your ViewHolder class:
private val setIconRunnable = Runnable { setFilledIcon() }

fun fillIconAt(timeFromNowMillis: Long) {
    itemView.removeCallbacks(setIconRunnable)
    if (timeFromNowMillis <= 0L) {
        setFilledIcon()
    } else {
        setEmptyIcon()
        itemView.postDelayed(setIconRunnable, timeFromNowMillis)
    }
}
```

```
// In your adapter class:
companion object {
    private const val ANIMATION_DURATION = 5000L
}

private var animationStartTime = 0L

fun initiateIconAnimation() {
    animationStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolderType, position: Int) {
    //...

    val iconChangeTime = (
            ANIMATION_DURATION * (position + 1).toFloat() / yourDataList.size
        ).roundToLong() + animationStartTime
    holder.fillIconAt(iconChangeTime - System.currentTimeMillis())
}
```

Comment: This answer should get a gold star.